# cwl files not getting updated

Tags: texstudio, auto-completion

I am using TeXstudio on macOS Monterey. I am facing the following scenario:

I have created the files `abc.tex` and `abc.sty` in some same folder. I compile them. But, seeing no autocompletion happening for the new commands that I define in `abc.sty`, I check the folder `/Users/atom/.config/texstudio/completion/autogenerated`. There is no problem here since a `cwl` file is automatically created here, named `abc.cwl`. But upon opening it, I see that it doesn't update as I add more commands to `abc.sty`.

I have tried quitting and relaunching TeXstudio but to no avail. I have also tried restarting my Mac, but again, nothing.

Can someone help me with this?

Comment: Could you attach your `abc.sty`?

Answer (score 0):

Autogenerated cwls do not update when you change the sty file. You can either manually update the cwl with your new commands, or delete abc.cwl after making changes to abc.sty and relaunch texstudio. In the second case the new autogenerated cwl will contain the added commands.

Comment: But it used to work fine in my Windows laptop, that I replaced with a MacBook less than 15 days ago.

Comment: I use windows and this is the behavior for as long as I've used texstudio (~3 years).

Comment: I can confirm that modifying autogenerated cwls indeed update the syntax checking. Also, this should not be posted as an answer, since it's not helpful at all, but also misleading.

Comment: It's not that editing the autogenerated cwl does not update highlighting; it does. I specifically said that modifying the .sty file will not be reflected in the autogenerated cwl if one was already generated. See edits to answer for clarification